# Ссылка на массив структур

Tags: visual-c++, структуры

Подскажите, как правильно передать ссылку на массив структур в функцию?

```
struct MyStruct
{
 char a[15];
 int s=0;
}MyStruct;

int funkciy(struct obyekt *f);
int _tmain()
{
 struct MyStruct obyekt[10];
 obyekt[0].s = 1;
 obyekt[1].s = 5;
 obyekt[2].s = 7;
 obyekt[0].a,'2';
 for (int z = 0; z < 10; ++z)
 {
  cout << " a= " << obyekt[z].a << " s= " << obyekt[z].s << endl;
 }
 funkciy(&obyekt);

 return 0;
}

int funkciy(struct obyekt *f)
{
 cin >> f[1].s=0;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вместо массива используйте тип vector, и проблем у вас не будет.

Comment: Немного не понятно, как создать вектор, включающий структуры там же разные типы данных?

Comment: Вектор может хранить любые типы данных, например, так:

    vector<MyStruct> theVector(10);

Comment: @eagl69, а зачем Вам тут ссылки? У Вас же написано:

    int funkciy(struct obyekt *f);

т.е. функция получает указатель. Для массива структур:

    struct MyStruct obyekt[10];


вызывая

   funkciy(obyekt);

Вы как раз передаете в `funkciy()` указатель на начало этого массива.

Вот и все.

Comment: @eagl69: Вы уж определитесь, вы пишете на C (`char a[15];`, `struct obyekt *f`) или на C++ (`cout`). Это совершенно разные языки.

Comment: @VladD, ну, все-таки не совершенно разные. 

Например, я по крайней мере стараюсь (там где это приемлемо), чтобы сишный код компилировался и g++.

Comment: @avp: Они разные по идеологии. То есть сишный код в основном будет компилироваться плюсами, но _идиоматический_ код на C очень далёк от идиоматического кода на плюсах. И наоборот. Но, что на C считается хорошим тоном (компактность, использование преимущества близости к машине), считается неправильным на плюсах. А то, что считается на плюсах хорошим тоном (абстракции, стандартные решения типа stl и смарт-пойнтеров, «скрывающие» адресную арифметику), считается неуместной игрой в бирюльки в C.

Comment: @avp: Соответственно хороший код на C будет плохим на плюсах и наоборот. Поэтому надо стараться писать в рамках лишь одной идеологии, на двух стульях не усидеть.

Comment: Немного изменил код, хочу, чтобы функция выполнялась в отдельном потоке:

struct dannye
{
 string a;
 int s = 0;
};

int _tmain()
{
 vector<dannye> obyekt(10);
 obyekt[0].s = 1;
 obyekt[1].s = 5;
 obyekt[2].s = 7;
 obyekt[0].a = "ffsss";
 obyekt[1].a = "lklklk";
 for (int z = 0; z < 10; ++z)
 {
  cout << " a= " << obyekt[z].a << " s= " << obyekt[z].s << endl;
 }
 thread funkciy_th(funkciy, &obyekt);
 Sleep(100);
 cout << obyekt[0].s << endl;
 Sleep(100000);
 return 0;
}
подключаемый файл 
#pragma once
int funkciy(vector<dannye> *f);

Comment: int funkciy(vector<dannye> *f)
{
 (*f)[0].s = 809;

 return 0;
}
так вот здесь пишет что идентификатор dannye не объявлен

Comment: @VladD как мне кажется, язык си считается подсобным в крестах, потому что на нем уже много готового кода написано, поэтому и кресты частично его поддерживают, для того чтоб не изобретать велосипеды. Поэтому если я в крестах вижу куски сишного кода, меня это не удивляет.

@eagl69, у вас прототип фунции другой, уберите из него звездочку.

Comment: @eagl69, наверное Вы имели в виду не *отдельный поток*, а *отдельную единицу компиляции* (модуль или по простому функцию в отдельном файле)?

Естественно, ругается, т.к. `struct dannye` не известна компилятору, когда он транслирует файл с функцией.

Решение -- поместите описание структуры в отдельном файле (скажем, `mydata.h`) и подключайте его в файлы .cpp (или какое там у Вас расширение для файлов с кодом?).

Примерно так:

     // file: main.cpp
     ...
     #include "mydata.h"
     ...
     main () {
       ...

     // file funk.cpp
     ...
     #include "mydata.h"
     int funkciy(...

Comment: Создал h файл поместил туда код:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

struct dannye
{
 int s;
 string a;
};
Вроде Вы так говорили... но компилятор ругается: Ошибка 1 error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "a" c:\projects\структуры1\структуры1\функция.h
убираю string все нормально.....
Ошибка 2 error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию c:\projects\структуры1\структуры1\функция.h 7 1 Структуры1

Немного не понял, что значит не надо компилировать файлы h/

Comment: @eagl69, файлы .h не надо компилировать.

Comment: @avp вы, как всегда, все усложняете. Он сидит под mvs и путает типы. А вы его еще в нагрузку линковщиком нагрузили. Вы высококлассный программист, я в этом не сомневаюсь, но вот мучить детей вы любите. )

Answer (score 1):

к примеру! читайте код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct myStruct{ // структура
    char c[3];  
};

void fillStruct(myStruct & m); // прототип функции

int main(){
    vector<myStruct> theStruct(10);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < theStruct.size(); i++){ // заполняем данные в структуре
        fillStruct(theStruct[i]);
        cout << theStruct[i].c[0] << theStruct[i].c[1] << theStruct[i].c[2] << endl; // выводим на экран для проверки
    }

    return 0;
}

void fillStruct(myStruct & m){ // передаем по ссылке
    m.c[0] = 'a'; // если захотите то можете сделать ввод "вручную"
    m.c[1] = 'b';
    m.c[2] = 'c';
}
```

Comment: @perfect, у меня там комментарии кончились.

TC явно же пишет, что хочет попробовать раздельную компиляцию (только почему-то пишет -- "хочу чтобы функция выполнялась в отдельном потоке").

На самом деле ему бы уйти с винды и IDE в linux с make, быстрее бы  во всем разобрался.

--

А вот передача аргументов по ссылке (вместо указателя), на мой взгляд -- одна из *худших* фич крестов (существенно усложняет поиск ошибок в чужих программах).

Comment: @avp странно, я четко понимаю, если передача по ссылке и не добавлено ключевое слово const, значит объект будет изменен внутри функции/метода. У меня с этим проблем не наблюдал. Передача по ссылке очень удобная штука для вывода данных из функции. Для меня ссылка очень элегантный вывод из функции, и не более, но, возможно, вы правы, я очень мало читаю чужого кода.

Comment: я считаю что изучения языка не операционная система типа nix'ов нужна а хорошая книга

Comment: @perfect, дело в том, что просматривая код (например, в выдаче grep) и не видя прототип функции,  по виду вызова невозможно определить может ли данная функция изменить значение аргумента.

Короче, на практике получается, что в большой программе надо внимательно разбирать намного больше кода.

Comment: @avp а вот поэтому я и уважаю сишников вроде вас, потому что вы умеете чужую "простыню" читать. Но думаю, со временем и ко мне это понимание прийдет, если в программировании останусь.